# openCV python - calcHist merge

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code for calculating and plotting the histrogam of an image.

```
colors = ('b', 'g', 'r')

for i, col in enumerate(colors):
    hist = cv2.calcHist([imgDEF], [i], None, [256], [1, 256])
    plt.plot(hist, color=col)

plt.show()
```

This code generate 3 histrograms for each rgb color. I need to sum each histogram to obtaim a single histrogram containing all the rgb colors because I need to calculate the mean and the standard deviation of the histogram.

So anyone could help me for:
1 - How to merge the three histogram in only single one;
2 - How to calculate the mean (or the std dev) for the total histogram?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain histogram representing all three colors of an RGB image, you can calculate histogram of intensity of all the pixels. For that, you just need to convert your image to grayscale and then compute the histogram. For example, like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imgDEF = cv2.imread("YOUR_IMAGE.jpg")
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgDEF, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
ghist = cv2.calcHist([imgGray], [0], None, [256], [0,256])

print ("Mean = {:.1f}, standard deviation = {:.1f}, total = {:.0f}".format(
    np.mean(ghist).item(),
    np.std(ghist).item(),
    np.sum(ghist).item()
))

plt.plot(ghist, color='m')
plt.show()
```

NOTE: It is expected that `total` (the sum of the histogram) will be equal to number of pixels in the image.

---

Original answer.

This will just average your histograms. But the meaning of that average will be somewhat ambiguous, since the sum of that average will probably not even be equal to the total number of pixels (as would be the case with any real histogram).

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imgDEF = cv2.imread("YOUR_IMAGE.jpg")

colors = ('b', 'g', 'r')

hist = {}
for i, col in enumerate(colors):
    hist[i] = cv2.calcHist([imgDEF], [i], None, [256], [1, 256])
    #plt.plot(hist[i], color=col)

ahist = (hist[0] + hist[1] + hist[2]) / 3

mean = np.mean(ahist).item()
std = np.std(ahist).item()
print ("Mean = {:.1f}, standard deviation = {:.1f}".format(mean, std))

plt.plot(ahist, color='m')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Andry and thanks for your answer!
Just for information..why when calculating ahist you divide by 3?
In this way you are calculating an average histo indeed of a total histo..do you agree?

Comment: @Joe, you are right. This is just an average of histograms. Originally I computed the average because if you just add up three histograms, the sum of that resulting histogram will exceed number of pixels. However, now I think more correct solution for you would be to compute histogram of the grayscale image representing your RGB image. I updated my answer to include that solution.